# SQL, show affected and non affected rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, left-join, rows-affected

Is there a way to show/return affected AND non-affected rows when I am doing a `LEFT JOIN` in SQL Server? The code below currently only returns affected rows.

For example:

```
SELECT 
    a.*, b.cost
INTO 
    Cost_Report_2016
FROM 
    Cost_Report_2017 a
LEFT JOIN 
    Part_Costs b 
WHERE 
    a.part_number = b.partnumber
```

Comment: dont directly you can use except and intersect to get the results you want not sure if this is what are you looking

Comment: Using @@ROWCOUNT and COUNT(*) - @@ROWCOUNT?

Comment: the affected rows shows how many were inserted. If you are wondering how many times the join condition was met then state that explicitly.

Comment: Do you mind showing some example code? Currently, this only returns affected rows, meaning this query only returns and displays rows where a.part_number = b.partnumber. However, I'd still like the a.part_number rows to be included in the results if it does not have a match with b.partnumber. Thank you.